# Resizing images in proportion to viewport, but keeping their relative positions similar

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website that has images over other images to show a switchboard background with switches as an overlay to represent on/off states. I'm trying to ensure that my website is useable across different resolutions but the images take up too much screen space on smaller devices. I need to scale all of the images proportionally while also maintaining their aspect ratios and relative positioning to each other.

I have yet to have much success regarding scaling this successfully. I'm seeking to emulate the scaling algorithm that web browsers use when you scale the page using CTRL+scroll.

I'm seeking an effect like the following
[![My rudimentary diagram][1]][1]

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The following is a picture of the site on a mobile device when I tried to use the vw/vh solution proposed. As you can see, even though the units are proposed in vw and vh, they don't align properly.

[image]

Edit 2: Full HTML and CSS of my most recent attempt here.

HTML

```
<div id="master_main_container" class="draggable panel_container">
    <div class="panel_header draggable_handle">Master<span class="close" id="master_close">&times;</span></div>
    <div id="panel_content_master" class="panel_content" > 
        <div id="master_switch_alt" class ="master_switch_off_alt"></div>
        <div id="master_switch_bat" class ="master_switch_off_bat"></div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

CSS

```
.panel_container {
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: #777777;
}

.panel_header{
    padding: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    color: white;                
    background-color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.panel_content {
    padding: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#panel_content_master {
    background-image: url(../images/masterPanelBg.jpg);
    padding-top: 107.73%;
    width: 9vw;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

#panel_content_breakers {
    background-image: url(../images/breakerrPanelBg.jpg); 
    padding-top: 32.39%;
    width: 30.4vw;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

#panel_content_switches {
    background-image: url(../images/switchesPanelBg.jpg); 
    padding-top: 76.82%;
    width: 12.7vw;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
}

#master_switch_alt {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16vh;
    left: 1.8vw;
    width: .75vw;
    padding-top: 364.29%;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    overflow: hidden;
}


#master_switch_bat {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16vh;
    left: 2.6vw;
    width: .75vw;
    padding-top: 364.29%;

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*Styling for the master Switch Off image  -- .master_switch_bat*/
.master_switch_off_alt{
    background-image: url(../images/masterOff.jpg);       
}

/*Styling for the master Switch On image */
.master_switch_on_alt{
    background-image: url(../images/masterOn.jpg);      
}

/*Styling for the master Switch Off image  -- BAT*/
.master_switch_off_bat{
    background-image: url(../images/masterOff.jpg);     
}

/*Styling for the master Switch On image -- BAT*/
.master_switch_on_bat{
    background-image: url(../images/masterOn.jpg);      
}
```

I know its all quite bad.

Comment: You should use viewport units (vh and vw) for the dimentions and the position of the elements.

Comment: While that solution works across devices with the same aspect ratio, it acts weird if you use CTRL+SCROLL or access the site from a different aspect ratio than 16:9.

Comment: background image should be set into backgrounds. you can lay more than one image in background, size each of them with background-size , background-repeat and background-position is also avalaible . are the black, blue and red lines your  background-image ?

Comment: The image provided is just  a mockup of the desired effect, I'll respond again when I've tested your suggestion.

Comment: @Siech0 I don't understand what you mean by "acts weird", show your CSS, show an usable example with real images, your problem is not clear

Comment: @arieljuod, an example of the issues described using your suggestion has been appended to the end of my post, if I have incorrectly implemented your suggestion please let me know.

Comment: You should provide a minimal CODE example (HTML AND CSS) to reproduce your problems. I don't now if you implemented something wrong since you are not showing how you are implementing it.

Comment: Full relevant source has been provided now. Its slightly modified from the original problems because I've been continuously attempting new strategies.

Comment: Why don't you use flexbox rather than absolute positioning? If it's all background-images, it shouldn't be a problem